# Using D3js, How to find the x,y coordinates after rotation of rectangle in plan?

Tags: d3.js

Y coordinate of rectangle after rotation on canvas. As shown in image the rectangle will be rotated on its center point axis.

I tried using this
x `= (x-c1)*con(rotation)-(y-c2)*sin(rotation)+c1; y` = (x-c1)*sin(rotation)+(y-c2)*cos(rotation)+c2;
where c1,c2 is the centre points of object or rectangle.

Help me give me proper solution......

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = d3.select("div");

const svg = canvas.append("svg").attr("width", "100vw").attr("height", "100vh");

const x = 200;
const y = 100;

const width = 300;
const height = 150;

const rect = svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", y)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("fill", "#0d002f")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

let topLeft = [x, y];
let topRight = [x + width, y];
let bottomLeft = [x, y + height];
let bottomRight = [x + width, y + height];


const centerCalculation = () => {
  return [width / 2 + x, height / 2 + y];
};

const [c1, c2] = centerCalculation();

const centerText = svg
  .append("text")
  .text("(" + c1 + "," + c2 + ")")
  .attr("dx", c1)
  .attr("dy", c2);

  const degree = Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
  const radians = () => {
    return (degree * Math.PI) / 180;
  };

  topLeft = calculateCoordinates(topLeft);
  topRight = calculateCoordinates(topRight);
  bottomLeft = calculateCoordinates(bottomLeft);
  bottomRight = calculateCoordinates(bottomRight);

  function calculateCoordinates(arr) {
    const x =
      c1 +
      (arr[0] - c1) * Math.cos(radians()) -
      (arr[1] - c2) * Math.sin(radians());
    const y =
      c2 +
      (arr[0] - c1) * Math.sin(radians()) +
      (arr[1] - c2) * Math.cos(radians());

    return [x, y];
  }


    const groupMain = svg
      .selectAll("g")
      .data([topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight]);

    const groupCoordinate = groupMain.enter().append("g");

    const gpText = groupCoordinate
      .append("text")
      .text((d, i) => {
        return "(" + d[0] + "," + d[1] + ")";
      })
      .attr("dx", (d) => {
        return d[0];
      })
      .attr("dy", (d) => {
        return d[1];
      });

  rect.attr("transform", "rotate(" + parseInt(degree) + "," + c1 + "," + c2 + ")");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="overflow: hidden;padding: 0;margin: 0;">
    

     <div style="background: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.925);width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;">
     
    </div>


     <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
     <!-- <script src="d3js.js"></script> -->
     <!-- <script src="objectRotation.js"></script> -->
     <!-- <script src="coordinationSystem.js"></script> -->
     <!-- <script src="zoomObject.js"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).